# Mock function module with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React Component which calls a method from another module.
The module just returns 1 method:

```
export default (url, method, authorization, body) => {
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  if (authorization) headers.Authorization = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
  return fetch(url, {
    method,
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }).then(res => res.json());
}
```

I'd like to mock this method/module, so the real code doesn't get called when testing the Components using it.
I'm a novice at React/Jest/Enzyme so I could be missing something easy.

In my test file:

```
jest.mock('../../utils/fetch.js', () => () => {
  Promise.resolve({_id: 1});
});
import fetch from '../../utils/fetch';
```

Where the method is used:

```
return fetch('/api/items', 'post', true, newItem).then(res => {
  this.props.history.push(`/items/${res._id}`);
}).catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a module that returns a function that will be return a promise. If you only want to test the happy path just return a resolved promise from your mock:

```
jest.mock('./my-function.js', () => () => Promise.resolve('foo'));
```

if you need to set the result of the function during your test mock the module with a spy and set the result later on in your test:

```
jest.mock('./my-function.js', () => jest.fn());
import myFunction from './my-function.js'
describe('foo',()=>{
  it('the happy pass',()=> {
     myFunction.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('foo'))
    //your assertion here 
  })

  it('when it fails',()=> {
     myFunction.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject())
     //your assertion here 
  })
})
})
```

Note that you have to mock it on top of the module. Otherwise you will have the original imported and later on replace the module with the mock, which will have no effect on the imported on. Think of mocking as a way to say jest how to resolve an import. So mocking something after importing it will have no effect.

Comment: I put `jest.mock('../../utils/fetch.js', () => () => {
                console.log('mocked fetch');
                Promise.resolve(undefined);
            });` in `beforeAll`. But the original method still gets called

Comment: I updated my answer to make clear that you have to mock it before you import it, as mocking will have no effect otherwise.

Comment: I actually didn't import the method at all because I don't use it in my test file. The Mock seems to work now, but i get `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Comment: Maybe you should post more of your code otherwise its hard to get what you have done so far.

Comment: I posted the full method + the use of said method.

Comment: In your code the mocked  function does not return the promise, please compare with my example should be `() => {return Promise...}`

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Just saw it, I used {} for the console.log and forgot to remove them.

Comment: I assume the mocking works now, how can I use fetch.mock.calls[0]?